# Random serial generating regex separator

Tags: javascript

The output of this code separates each 4 digits by a hyphen(-) with the regex **\w**, but it doesn't work if I replace **\w** to other regular expressions. Why is that?

*This one works perfectly.*

```js
function gen(length, separator) {
  var license = new Array(length + 1).join((Math.random().toString(36) + '00000000000000000').slice(2, 18)).slice(0, length);
  return license.toUpperCase().replace(/(\w{4})/g, '$1' + separator).substr(0, length + Math.round(length/4)-1);
}
document.write(gen(16, '-'));
```

*This one does not separates by a hyphen each 4 digits.*

```js
function gen(length, separator) {
  var license = new Array(length + 1).join((Math.random().toString(36) + '00000000000000000').slice(2, 18)).slice(0, length);
  return license.toUpperCase().replace(/([A-Z]{4})/g, '$1' + separator).substr(0, length + Math.round(length/4)-1);
}
document.write(gen(16, '-'));
```

Comment: can you add some examples to illustrate the problem?

Comment: And what are you trying to replace it with?

Comment: `/([a-z0-9]{4})/gi` works as expected. What kind of regex doesn't work?

Comment: @casraf And I also tried using `.`, that works too

Comment: @Somrlik I'm trying to replace it with alphabets [A-Z]

Comment: @casraf the alphabets regex [A-Z]

Comment: @skygate Alphabet alone won't work because you have numbers in your hash. They will be left out of the matching process, and only sequences of 4 LETTERS would be appended with dash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
function gen(length, separator) {
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  var text = '';
  for( var i=0; i < length; i++ ) {
      text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
      if(i%4 == 3 && i<length-1) text += separator;
  }

  return text;
}
document.write(gen(16, '-'));
```